# How to use an array which is returned from 1 function in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have 1 function in Nodejs that return a list of recipient:

```
var recipientList = [];
userService.listUser().then( result => {
    var listPSID = result.filter(result => !'279'.includes(result));
    recipientList = listPSID.slice();
    console.log(recipientList);
});
```

Now I want to access that list OUTSIDE the function, something likes:

```
console.log(recipientList[0]);
```

How can I do that? Thank you all.

Comment: Continue the promise chain or use a callback.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Promises, you cannot access it outside the function. If you use `async / await` instead, it should work.

```
async function getList(){
    let result = await userService.listUser();
    var listPSID = result.filter(result => !'279'.includes(result));
    recipientList = listPSID.slice();
    console.log(recipientList[0]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but what I expected is like:
async function getList(){
    recipientList = listPSID.slice();
};
const abc = recipientList[1];
Is there any way to do that?

Comment: @tuanha1709 You can initialize the variable outside the function possibly, but I still don't think it will be possible since it is async.